# Flask WTForms error when try to populate data in QuerySelectField

Tags: flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I try to populate **QuerySelectField** from my function who return list of year periode. But I got error

```
sqlalchemy.orm.exc.UnmappedInstanceError: Class 'builtins.str' is not mapped
```

This my code:

form.py

```
class TahunAuditForm(Form):
    def get_list_tahun():
        """Looping year from 1990 to 2025"""
        years = {}
        for yr in range(1990, 2025):
           years[str(yr) + '-' + str(yr+1)] = [str(yr) + '-' + str(yr+1)]
        return years

    tahun = QuerySelectField(
        _('Year'),
        query_factory = get_list_tahun,
        allow_blank=True,
        blank_text=_('-- choose year --')
    )
    start = DateTimeField(_('Start Periode'))
    end = DateTimeField(_('End Periode'))
```

I hope advanced can help, whats wrong in my code and how to populate data to **QuerySelectField**.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45877050/flask-populate-selectfield-choices-with-array)

This is the code I use:

```
# function 
def get_list_tahun_audit():
   """Looping year from 1990 to 2025"""
   return [(str(yr), str(yr) + '-' + str(yr + 1)) for yr in range(2000, 2025)]


class TahunAuditForm(Form):
    def get_list_tahun():
        list_tahun = get_list_tahun_audit()
        return list_tahun[::-1]

    tahun = SelectField('Tahun', choices=get_list_tahun())
    start = DateTimeField(_('Start Periode'))
    end = DateTimeField(_('End Periode'))
```

I Hope this can help someone, happy coding...